# Yamaha P-105 + korg module x5dr ( how to connect?)

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, korg

i just like to ask something and need your confirmation if these particulars will work together. 
I have yamaha P-105 and i want to connect it to korg module x5dr. It says i need to have a usb-midi host to connect the two. Is this midiplus works well with P-105 and x5dr?
Many thanks!
[image]